# jquery replace word with element a

Tags: jquery, json, replace

with jQuery I have this for example:
simple json:

```
var data = {"words": [
 {"word":"angry", "wordtext":"<p>I&acute;m very very <strong>angry</strong>.</p>"},
 {"word":"tired",  "wordtext":"<p>I&acute;m very very <strong>tired</strong>.</p>"}
]};
```

some paragraph:

```
<p>bla bla bla bla **angry** bla bla bla **tired** bla bla bla ...</p>
```

and i want to replace inside the paragraph, if exist, the word (eg. "angry") with:

```
<a href="some">word</a>
```

Comment: That's not JSON, it's a regular javascript object. I'm guessing you only want to replace the word inside the paragraph, and not the occerences outside the paragraphs, and are the "word" keys in the object somehow related to this, and should be used for something? How do you know where the paragraphs are, are they always in "wordtext", and is the object always structured like this? ***Way too little*** information given to be able to solve this !

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\*\*(.+?)\*\*
```

and replace it with:

```
<a href="some">$1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get text and replace as html

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text().replace(/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
    $(this).html(txt)
})
```

Comment: my guess is that he wants to replace the word angry without the star entities, i thing they are just for marking..

Answer (score 0):

Your Html  and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/symonsarwar/Vz9Hj/7/)

```
<a href="some" id="yourid">word</a>
```

Your js

```
$(function(){
    var i=0;
$.each(data.words[i],function(index,item){
   // alert(item)
    i++;
    if(item=='angry'){
    $('#yourid').html(item);
    }
});
});
```